# NonlinearModelFit reproducibility

Tags: nonlinear

I have a big data set about 10,000 points of 3 independent variables. I am fitting with `NonlinearModelFit` command. After this, I specified 3 values for three variables to model fit and it gave me a value (say 0.18).

Now, I repeat the test by taking the coefficients separately and using them in the analytical function for which I found the same using the above command. But now I get different value like 21.0. 
I wonder how can it be?
The coefficients I get using `fit["BestFitParameters"]` where `fit` is the function I defined while fittting. Any help is appreciated.

Writting the polynomial and its internal polynomial is difficult as they are lengthy having 450 terms or so.

Comment: Any code would be appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what you're doing. Please post some minimal code that allows to reproduce the issue. Each time you fit to the same dataset you must get the same result. But then you're doing something (the second paragraph) that I can't understand.

Comment: `NonlinearModelFit` will find a local optimum for the fit in your parameter space. There may be different local optima, and dependend on how you setup the problem, you may find different optima.

Comment: By "450 terms" do you mean 450 parameters that are estimated?

Comment: Yes. 450 means there are 450 parameters to be found out. It is huge. I get two different answer from the one of model fit directly and from the explicitely rewritten model function using the estimated parameter obtained from nonlinear fit. This is the problem.